# How can I find the disk available in a Chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra

While a Chef recipe is executing, I want to determine if there is sufficient free disk space available to perform an operation.

How best to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Ohai](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai.html) detects certain properties of a a node each time it is run. These properties are captured as [automatic attributes](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai_automatic_attributes.html) and are available to you as node attributes.

The attribute node['filesystem'] contains information about each of the devices on your system. To get the space available in kb, for a specific device:

```
node['filesystem']['/dev/xvda1']['kb_available']
```

The following is an example of the filesystem attribute JSON from Ohai:

```
   "filesystem": {
  "/dev/xvda1": {
    "kb_size": "521882300",
    "kb_used": "119914572",
    "kb_available": "375474240",
    "percent_used": "25%",
    "mount": "/",
    "fs_type": "ext4",
    "mount_options": [
      "rw"
    ],
    "uuid": "248b8180-f75f-48fc-a8be-e3ff3506c4d6"
  },
  "tmpfs": {
    "kb_size": "1987292",
    "kb_used": "0",
    "kb_available": "1987292",
    "percent_used": "0%",
    "mount": "/dev/shm",
    "fs_type": "tmpfs",
    "mount_options": [
      "rw",
      "rootcontext=\"system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0\""
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
cron 'cron for checking disk space' do
  minute '00'
  hour  '12'
  command 'disk_space_check.sh'
  user 'smj'
end
```