# How to find the total disk space in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I wanted to find the **total disk space** available in the machine through chef. I could find a way to find individual partition space via node['filesystem']['device_name'], but is there any way to find total disk space?

Comment: Use some ruby code to sum it up?

Comment: @StephenKing Thanks for the reply! Yeah I could do that, but is there another way? I could even execute a command to get the total size by this command `df | grep '^/dev/[hs]d' | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s/1048576}` but  I wanted to make use of ohai.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the disk available in a Chef recipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286709/how-can-i-find-the-disk-available-in-a-chef-recipe)

Comment: @Sergiu Not a duplicate question, as I'm looking to find the total available,  not individual device on the disk. That's why I've specifically mentioned **Total**

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific answer because that's not a concept that your OS understands. You could do the simple answer of loop over all devices and add up free space, but that would probably end up with incorrect data because of things like virtual devices (procfs, devfs, sysfs, etc), tempfs devices, loopback mounts, etc. What you *probably* want is to loop over all devices matching some name pattern but the specifics of that pattern depend on your OS and hardware: `node['filesystem'].select {|k, v| k =~ /something/ }.map {|k, v| v['kb_available'] }.sum`

Comment: Looping over all mounted devices will also pick up remote mounts (NFS, SSHFS, etc.) and bind mounts and countless other things.  So yeah, probably a terrible idea to loop over all mounted devices.

Comment: @coderanger Thanks for your reply.I actually wanted a generic answer that could work on all OS. But for now I ended up using a shell command get the total available space.                                                       
    `df | grep '^/dev/[hs]d' | awk '{s+=$4} END {print s/1048576}`

Comment: That `^/dev/[hs]d` as a filter pattern is very specific to Linux, and not even all Linux (many cloud systems these days use `xd` drivers).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the command df -Th --total and last line of this command print the total assigned space and total used.